# swift sort characters in a string

Tags: arrays, string, swift, sorting, character

How to sort characters in a string e.g. "5121" -> "1125"  ?

I can do this with code below but it seems too slow:

```
var nonSortedString = "5121"
var sortedString = String(Array(nonSortedString.characters).sort())
```

Comment: *"it seems too slow"* – do you have concrete numbers?

Comment: If it works and is not a perceptible performance problem it is fine.

Comment: Well, I have a code in swift and similar code in c++ which is much faster. So I supposed that this conversion string->array->string  sows down.
in c++ I have std::sort(stringToSort.begin(), stringToSort.end());

Comment: Concrete speed doesn't really matter, what matters is the complexity (big Oh notation). Also you can't compare string handling between C++ and Swift because Swift has a much more advanced string management structure, with full Unicode support and everything. What happens when there's a compound character in C++? It will look like crap afterwards. Swift though can handle all that, emojis don't get destroyed, everything gets sorted according to human intuition.

Answer (score 2):

The `CharacterView` handles properly compound characters and provides proper ordering ("eěf" vs. "efě"). If you are ok with the way C++ handles unicode characters, try using one of the other views, like `nonSortedString.utf16.sort()`. It should give speed similar to C++.

Comment: thank you. this helped me to increase the speed in 3.5 times
(sorry, I can't vote for the answer because my reputation is low)

Comment: In swift this converts to utf16 numbers I think. How do you convert the numbers array back to a string?